# Content area in masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a master page using an html file shared by the UI developer. Now, I'm getting the entire page as masterpage for all the pages in the site. The problem is that, the original data is showing after the entire masterpage area. How can we add the content inside the masterpage area itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Content goes inside masterpage PlaceholdermMin through page layouts.

If we are talking SharePoint 2013 then: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822368.aspx

If it is SharePoint 2010 then: http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1125

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its 2013 only. Is it possible to apply a masterpage specific to pages ?